# Wordpress - Set a Drop Down For Featured Image To Change Background Position Depending on Page

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress, sass

Right now my featured image for a page template is pulled from the standard Featured Image option on the right side of the new page.

I have my CSS in my stylesheet that says object-fit: cover since it's an absolute image instead of a background image

Each image is positioned a little differently and what i'd like to do is make it so that i can set a specific object-position: x x for each image.

So, for one image, if it's cutting off someones head, i could change it to object-position: center bottom; for example or vice versa.

Does anyone know the best way of doing this ? Any way for some plugin that would allow me to dictate lets say 3 options based off a drop down from the backend of WP like:

Background:
Option 1: center top
Option 2: center
Option 3: center bottom

And then in the CSS i could set a class that would correspond to those? This way each featured image doesn't need to be one way.

Thanks!

Comment: You'd find it much easier to just manipulate the image itself to be updated to what you want to be shown.

Comment: You can use a meta box generator plugin like [ACF](https://wordpress.org/plugins/advanced-custom-fields/) to generate the options you need.

Comment: @valenjeb - thought about that --- we're already using ACF for the site but wouldn't i need to create a different field for the featured image then? Id rather utilize the featured image of Wordpress for the top header image for each interior page

Comment: Not at all. You can still use the WP featured image. You just add an additional field/s as you need and then use its value on the frontend as you would do with any other meta data

Answer (score 0):

Rather than adding another plugin (though Pods or ACF would be the easiest route), you could do this relatively simply by leveraging WP built-in features.

**1. First enable custom fields in your post edit screen**
Hit the three dots in the top-right; then go to *Preferences*, then enable *Custom fields*.

**2. Add a custom field at the bottom of the post edit screen.**
Give your custom field a name (say, "photo-style") and then its value is a single class name that you can switch out depending on needs, e.g. "photo-center", "photo-top", etc.

**3. In *Admin -> Tools -> Theme File Editor* add the following to your Theme Functions file**

```
add_filter( 'body_class', function( $classes ) {
            $my_post = get_the_ID();
            $new_class = get_post_meta($my_post, 'photo-style', true);
            if($new_class !== "false") {
                return array_merge( $classes, array( $new_class ) );
            }
            return $classes;
        } );
```

**4. Now, when you load your post, you can open page inspector and see the page body has your new class name ("photo-center, etc.") added.**
Then you can make whatever CSS changes you need to in customizer and you're set.

The only drag is that you'll need to remember to add the custom field every time. Maybe not a major issue if it's a site you'll be managing yourself, but were it for a customer I'd think about a more easy-to-manage solution.

**UPDATE. If you're using ACF**

- Ignore steps 1 and 2 above. Go to Custom Fields in admin. Add a new field group, setting it to display on posts/pages etc as you need.
- Make it a select, with the options you want (center, center-top, etc.) and set its *name* to "photo-style". Edit one of your posts and select the right photo styling from the new dropdown.
- Steps 3 and 4 are the same as above. Add the new function then style with css. If you check dev tools you'll see that *body* now has the class you selected from your drop-down list on it. You could then do something like:

  body.center-top .wp-featured-image {
  object-fit:top;
  }

  body.center .wp-featured-image {
  object-fit:center;
  }

Comment: Thanks - very concise  -- everything makes sense except for #2.  Can u explain that more? Using pages vs posts also.

Already using ACF on site so I'm ok going that route. Ideally would want the featured image on the page to be selected and then an ACF option below it or somewhere where i could add a class for either center top or center bottom (we can assume that the default in the css would be object-fit: center so these other options would override that style. 

Possible to use WP featured image with ACF so that i can add a drop down under the Featured Image to select one of 3 options?

Comment: Yes! If you've already got ACF then it's even easier. Just add a new field group applicable to the post type you want. You could make it a select drop down if you like with the three different options. Then the rest of my code is the same, you just make sure that in my functions.php snipet you reference the name of the field you added.

Comment: a little lost - i added the code you provided in the functions.php and i'm pretty experienced with ACF but i've never using ACF to select an option from a dropdown that would then add it to the featured image. 

There seems to be 3 things in play:
1.) adding the functions code
2.) adding some ACF variable to my existing header code that pulls the image based on the featured image
3.) creating 3 separate CSS classes (center center / center top / center bottom)

Comment: What type of field am i adding within the ACF field / and also what LOCATION is it assigned to?  You can see my existing php code here: https://ibb.co/882pfsB

Answer (score 0):

You should implement a custom meta field (a plugin like ACF or CMB2 is the easiest solution) and then use its value on the frontend.

```
<?php

if (has_post_thumbnail()) {
    $post_id = get_the_ID();
    $custom_class = get_post_meta($post_id, 'my_custom_image_class', true);
    // ACF example
    // $custom_class = get_field('my_custom_image_class', $post_id);
    
    the_post_thumbnail('post-thumbnail', ['class' => $custom_class]);
}
```

Comment: Thanks - code in my page template is:
-----
  <header class="img-bg-page-header">
   <?php if (has_post_thumbnail()) {
    the_post_thumbnail('original', array('class' => 'bg-img'));
    the_title('<h1 class="page-title">', '</h1>');
   }
   ?>
  </header>
------

1.) Do i create a new group in ACF and apply it to all custom page templates ?
2.) i'd then create a new group called "Featured Image Position" ?
3.) under that, what would be the fields though and how would i adjust this?
4.) then in my CSS i'd add 2 CSS classes (center top , center bottom) but how do i then assign it